# could not load type "my_form" symfony3

Tags: symfony

After upgrading to Symfony3, my forms didn't work anymore. I am currently getting the message:

```
Could not load type "my_entity_form"
```

The form is defined as a service in MyBundle/Resources/config/form.xml, and is loaded through dependency injection. The bundle is registered, the files seems to be loading correctly.

Here is the form defined as a service:

```
<!-- MyEntity FormType -->
<service id="form.type.my_entity" class="MyVendor\MyBundle\Form\Type\MyEntityType">
  <tag name="form.type" alias="my_entity_form"/>
</service>
```

and this is my form type

```
namespace MyVender\MyBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class MyEntityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(...));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyVender\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_entity_form';
    }

}
```

Anyone has an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Yep.  Forms have changed in Symfony 3.  A lot.  Forms no longer have names or aliases.  All I can suggest is to read the docs carefully again: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service

Comment: your link is referring to the "custom field type". you probably meant this link: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services. however, my setup is exactly like that as far as i can tell

Comment: My link has more details on defining form types as services.  Look closely at the getName and alias stuff.  It's been dropped in S3.  You did not show how the form type is being used but I am guessing that you are using 'my_entity_form' instead of MyEntityType::class

Comment: Downgrade to Symfony 2.8 and check your logs (or the web debug toolbar) for deprecation notices.

Comment: Hi @apfz, did you figure that out? I reach the same issue "Could not load type "my_form_type"", I don't get it: in the controller, I define the form like $form = $this->createForm('my_form_type',....) and the service is defined with title: "form.type.my_form_type" pointing to the class "AppBundle\Form\MyFormType".  It seems to me that I follow the rules described in the doc but it doesn't work out, so if you have some hint that'd be welcome.

Comment: yes.. forms are not considered as services anymore. just load the class name directly like so: $this->createForm(MyFormType::class)

Comment: Thanks, I m good to keep on going now.